# Is passing by reference then copying and passing by value functionally different?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Is there a functional difference between:

```
void foo(const Bar& bar) {
  Bar bar_copy(bar);
  // Do stuff with bar_copy
}
```

and

```
void foo(Bar bar) {
  // Do stuff with bar
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `Bar bar_copy(bar);`?

Comment: oops, yeah. I wrote it correctly in my term and didn't copy it over. Sorry.

Comment: I've been using this to declare functions taking incomplete types (by reference), definitions of which are later included in `.cpp` file.

Comment: @LogicStuff you use the top one? Why can't you do that with the bottom one?

Comment: @wrhall Because parameter in function declaration must be **complete** type if it's not passed by reference or pointer.

Comment: @wrhall - the compiler needs to know how to construct (and of course allocate) `Bar`, as it is put on the stack before the function call. The size of the object needs to be known by the caller. So it has to be completely specified. References and pointers are only passed as a pointer (typically) which has a known size (i.e. `sizeof(void*)`) so you don't need to know what size object you have until you are inside the function.

Comment: @LogicStuff: Wrong. It only needs to be complete at the point of use and at the point of definition, The declaration needs only know a name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there is a valuable difference.

`void foo(Bar bar)` can copy-construct **or** move-construct `bar`, depending on the calling context.

And when a temporary is passed to `foo(Bar bar)`, your compiler may be able to construct *that temporary* directly where `bar` is expected to be.  Hat tip to template boy.

Your function `void foo(const Bar& bar)` always performs a copy.

Your function `void foo(Bar bar)` **may** perform a copy or a move or possibly neither.

Comment: You also miss out on an optimization opportunity as when the initializer to the parameter is a temporary the copy or move can be elided entirely.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, there are differences. While the most obvious one is that the type of the function changes (and thus the type of its function pointer), there are also some less obvious implications:

#### Move-constructible but not copy-constructible `Bar`

For example, assume the following call to `foo`:

```
foo(Bar());
```

For the first version, this will be passed by a reference to `const bar` and then copied using the copy constructor. For the second version, the compiler will attempt the move-constructor first.

This means, that the only the second version can be called by types that are move-constructible only, like `std::unique_ptr`. [In fact, the manually forced copy will not even allow compilation of the function](https://ideone.com/V1zNSM).

Obviously, this can be mitigated by adding a slight complication:

```
void foo(Bar&& bar) {
    // Do something with bar.
    // As it is an rvalue-reference, you need not copy it.
}

void foo(Bar const& bar) {
    Bar bar_copy(bar);
    foo(std::move(bar_copy));
}
```

#### Access specifiers

Interestingly, there is another difference: The context in which access permissions are checked.

Consider the following `Bar`:

```
class Bar
{
    Bar(Bar const&) = default;
    Bar(Bar&&) = default;

public:
    Bar() = default;

    friend int main();
};
```

Now, the reference-and-copy version will error out, while the parameter-as-value version will not complain:

```
void fooA(const Bar& bar)
{
    //Bar bar_copy(bar); // error: 'constexpr Bar::Bar(const Bar&)' is private
}

void fooB(Bar bar) { } // OK
```

Since we have declared `main` to be a friend, the following call [is allowed](https://ideone.com/PmyURg) (note that the friend would not be necessary if, e.g. the actual call was made in a `static` member function of `Bar`):

```
int main()
{
    fooB(Bar()); // OK: Main is friend
}
```

#### Completeness of `Bar` at the call site

As has been observed in the comments, if you wish `Bar` to be an incomplete type *at the call site*, it is possible to use the pass-by-reference version, as this does not require the call site to be able to allocate an object of type `Bar`.

#### Copy Elision Side-Effects

C++11 12.8/31:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. In such cases,
>   the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two different
>   ways of referring to the same object [...]
>
> - [...]
> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>     to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
> - [...]

Obviously, only the call-by-value version meets this criterium - after passing by reference, the parameter is bound to a reference after all. [Beyond an observable difference](https://ideone.com/KHTgHZ), this also means that an optimization oppurtunity is lost.

Answer (score 4):

There are some differences.

```
void foo(const Bar& bar) {
  Bar bar_copy(bar);
  // Do stuff with bar_copy
}
```

doesn't allow to avoid the copy even if `bar` was a temporary and avoid also the move of `bar`.

Comment: Does that make it strictly worse if you can just pass by value [ie there is a comment on the question that says they use pass-by-reference and then copy for functions taking incomplete types, which they presumably can't use in the pass-by-value version]?

Comment: @wrhall: If you pass by value, you allow move construction of `bar` and from `bar`.

Comment: Right -- so in the case where you can pass by value, you probably should, right? Or are there reasons not to?

Comment: As state in the comment, for *forward declaration*. For "simplicity", as the preferred way is to pass by const reference in other case which is more frequent.